# How can I fix this fatal exception?

Tags: android, cygwin, android-ndk, gnu-make

I am porting my C/C++ code into an Android Game using the NDK, but I'm having trouble getting started.

I have downloaded the NDK-r5b from developer.android.com and I have installed Cygwin.

I am not even able to run the `Hello-jni` program provided within the NDK samples.

When I run:

```
$ cd /cygdrive/c/android/android-ndk-r5b/samples/hello-jni 
$ ndk-build
```

I get an `ERROR: You are using a non-Cygwin compatible Make program`.

I tried installing GNUMake 3.81 but the problem persists.

---

I tried to run the `HELLO-JNI` sample program in the NDK through Eclipse IDE. There is a force close on the Android AVD, and logcat was showing an exception as follows:

```
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): 
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 
2577) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java: 
2679) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit 
$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274): Caused by: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library hello-jni not found 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     at 
com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.<clinit>(HelloJni.java:67) 
04-08 12:32:11.609: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(274):     ... 15 more 
04-08 12:32:11.678: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing 
activity com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni 
04-08 12:32:12.340: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout 
for HistoryRecord{44f925c8 com.example.hellojni/.HelloJni}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and I figured it out. The thing that was causing it to mess up for me was in Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Build command: was set to 'bash ndk-build' instead of 'bash C:\android-ndk-r6\ndk-build'

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. It turned out that the GNU tool chain was not installed when I installed Cygwin, and make was being picked up from another SDK installed on my build machine. The fix was to reinstall Cygwin and check that the Gnu tools were installed. (I think the heading is 'Devel' in the Cygwin setup. The default is not to install, change to 'install'). HTH

Answer (score 1):

I tackled this in Eclipse by doing the following:

1. Right click on the project name and choose "properties"
2. In the "C/C++ Build" choose "builder section" then in the "builder" group put the following in the "build command" textbox:

   bash "_cygwin_home_\home\android-ndk-r6b\ndk-build"

   - replace "_cygwin_home_" with your actual path to cygwin,
   - I place the ndk folder inside the home folder in the cygwin installtion folder(as you can see).

I hope this help you.